# Unable to load dlib in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, dlib

I'm creating a function in AWS Lambda that uses the DLIB package. I have it working fine locally, then to make sure i compile the binaries correctly I created an EC2 instance based upon the [AMI information given by Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html), but I can't seem to package my dependencies correctly.

This is the error I'm receiving from AWS Lambda when I attempt to test my function:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /var/task/site-packages/dlib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Inside my package (kept in S3 as it's 49mb), I have my `lambda_function.py` file, and then two subdirectories, named `libs` and `site-packages`. `Libs`contains files such as `liblapack.so`, `libquadmath.so`, `libstdc++.so.6` etc.

The `site-packages` directory then contains all my dependencies for my python code - `CV`, `Numpy` and `Dlib`. I've been banging my head on the table for a couple of days now. For the life of me I can't figure out how to instruct lambda to use the `libstdc++.so.6` I have given in the `libs` directory.

I think i'm linking all the packages correctly inside `lambda_function.py`

```
import sys
import os

# Import installed packages (in site-packages and lib)
CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

site_pkgs = os.path.join(CWD, "site-packages")
lib_pkgss = os.path.join(CWD, "libs")

sys.path.append(site_pkgs)
sys.path.append(lib_pkgss)

import json
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib
import boto3
...
```

Any ideas what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the site-packages folder. Instead, zip the files inside the site-packages folder and the complete lib folder and upload it to AWS lambda(through S3 bucket). It should work then. The folder structure which worked for me is this.

```
├── dlib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── easy_install.py
├── lambda_function.py
├── lib
│   ├── libgfortran.so.3
│   ├── libopenblas.so.0
│   └── libquadmath.so.0          # only these three are needed.
├── pip
├── pip-10.0.1.dist-info
├── pkg_resources
├── setuptools
├── setuptools-39.0.1.dist-info
├── numpy
└── any other packages you might have(like scikit opencv etc)
```

Zip this folder and then upload it to lambda. You don't need to manually link inside the code as you did using `sys.path.append()` and `os.path.join()` , so remove those lines. AWS lambda will automatically load the shared libraries from the `lib` folder.

Comment: Amazing! I will try this when I get time. Thank you for the response :)

Comment: What error did you get? Also when you zip the file don't include the top level folder.

Comment: So, I realised when I was uploading I was getting a different error in Lambda which I missed, the lib folder has worked. Just recompiling DLIB using Amazons AMI.